# ifelse categorizing in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to create a new categorical variable category based on the range of the x variable.

what I have done is this:

```
data$category <- ifelse(data$x >= 780, 6,
                      ifelse(750 =< data$x <= 779, 5,
                      ifelse(714 =< data$x <= 749, 4,
                      ifelse(679 =< data$x <= 713, 3,
                      ifelse(660 =< data$x <= 678, 2,
                      ifelse(640 =< data$x <= 659, 1, NA))))))
```

its returning Error: unexpected '<=' in...

any suggestion?

Comment: `ifelse(750 <= data$x & data$x <= 779, 5,...` (note `<=`, not `=<`), but, as @lebatsnok noted, `cut` is easier: `data$category = cut(data$x, breaks=c(-Inf, 640,660,679,714,750,778,Inf), labels=c(NA,1:6))`

Comment: For future reference, if you do need to explicitly test for category membership, you might find the `between` function useful (it's in the `dplyr` package). `between(data$x, 640, 659)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `cut` instead of this approach.

[edit] eipi10 showed in a comment how to do it-- but I'd suggest two changes:

```
 d$cat <- cut(d$x, c(640, 660, 679, 714, 750, 780, Inf)-1 , labels=FALSE)
```

- breaks should be lower than x to include x (or you could use include.lowest)
- if you set `labels=FALSE` then you automatically get consecutive integers as labels
- no need to have -Inf as the lowest break, anything less than the lowest one will automatically set to zero

As you see, this is much easier than to have lots of nested `ifelse`'s.

A stylistic thing: it is not a good idea to call your data frame `data` -- this is the name of a base function (but nothing will immediately happen if you do it).

Answer (score 2):

R does not support the syntax `750 =< data$x <= 779`. Change it to `750 <= data$x & data$x <= 779`. This holds for all the ranges in your code.